# Receiver's receiving Multiple copies of e-mails from sender when a single email is sent

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

it will be sent 2 - 8 times within minutes. This is not happening all the time, nor does it happen every time they email the same recipient; it just seems to be random.

My mail code is

```
SmtpClient oSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        oSmtpClient.Port = oSmtpSection.Network.Port;
        oSmtpClient.EnableSsl = bool.Parse(oSmtpSection.Network.EnableSsl.ToString());
        oSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        oSmtpClient.Host = oSmtpSection.Network.Host;
        oSmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(oSmtpSection.Network.UserName, oSmtpSection.Network.Password);

        //Add this line to bypass the certificate validation
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s,
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
                System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };
```

Please help.

Comment: Almost certainly, what's actually happening is that you're sending multiple emails, but you just haven't isolated how or why this is happening yet. If it's not that, then the next thing to look at is whether there's some component (such as an anti-virus system) that's installed in the email system and has been configured to misbehave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't have the problem you are looking for. You must be calling this method (piece of code) from some other method. That method is getting called multiple times. You need to debug/log here to know how many times this is called.

Comment: I already reviewed my code. No any loop before method calling. When i change password of mail account then working fine some days.

Comment: This code is also working fine on local. When i host on server then some time create problem.